# How do I make an extension's html background invisible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I´m trying to do a test extension for chrome for a university project but I can´t find a way to make the background or body of the extension´s html completely invisible, just for a clean interface. The problems I´m having are those white corners on the background.

This is the code of the extension:

```js
// Define variables
let audio, playbtn, title, poster, artists, mutebtn, seekslider, volumeslider, 
seeking = false, seekto, curtimetext, durtimetext, playlist_status, dir, playlist, 
ext, agent, playlist_artist, repeat, randomSong;

// Initialization of YouTube Api

var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
var id = '5_385OOZlIg';
var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id;

// Initialization of Array of Music, Tittle, Poster Image, Artists

dir = "music/";
playlist = ["Cartoon-On-_-On","Elektronomia","Johnning","Popsicle","Fearless"];
title = ["Cartoon - On & On","Elektronomia","Janji-Heroes Tonight","Popsicle","Lost Sky - Fearless"];
artists = ["(feat. Daniel Levi) [NSC Release]","Elektronomia - Sky High [NCS Release]","(feat. Johnning) [NCS Release]",
"LFZ - [NCS Release]","(feat. Chris Linton)[NCS Release]"];
poster = ["images/ncs1.jpeg","images/ncs2.jpg","images/ncs3.jpg","images/ncs4.jpg","images/ncs5.jpg"];

// Used to run on every browser

ext = ".mp3";
agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if(agent.indexOf('firefox') != -1 || agent.indexOf('opera') != -1){
    ext = ".ogg";
}

// Set object references

playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
nextbtn = document.getElementById("nextbtn");
prevbtn = document.getElementById("prevbtn");
mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
visibilitybtn = document.getElementById("visibility");
seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
curtimetext = document.getElementById("curtimetext");
durtimetext = document.getElementById("durtimetext");
playlist_status = document.getElementById("playlist_status");
playlist_artist = document.getElementById("playlist_artist");
repeat = document.getElementById("repeat");
randomSong = document.getElementById("random");

playlist_index = 0;

// Audio Object

audio = new Audio();
audio.src = dir + playlist[0] + ext; // music/musicname.mp3
audio.loop = false;

// First song title and artist

playlist_status.innerHTML = title[playlist_index];
playlist_artist.innerHTML = artists[playlist_index];

// Add event handling

playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause);
nextbtn.addEventListener("click", nextSong);
prevbtn.addEventListener("click", prevSong);
mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);
visibilitybtn.addEventListener("click", toggle);
seekslider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){seeking = true; seek(event);});
seekslider.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){seek(event);});
seekslider.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){seeking = false;});
volumeslider.addEventListener("mousemove", setvolume);
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){seektimeupdate();});
audio.addEventListener("ended",function(){switchTrack();});
repeat.addEventListener("click", loop);
randomSong.addEventListener("click", random);

// Functions
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '315',
        width: '560',
        videoId: id,
        
        playerVars: {'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0,  'loop': 1},
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
/*
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    let pgd = player.getDuration();
    let vpb = document.getElementById("video_progress_bar");
    vpb.setAttribute("max",pgd);
}*/
//Intento de que la barra de progreso avance con forme al video onPlayerStateChange(event) y onPlay()
var testThread;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data == 1)
    {
      testThread = setInterval(seektimeupdate,500);
    }else{
        clearInterval(testThread);
    }
}
// Oculta o hace visible el video de YouTube en la interfaz
function toggle(element){
    let ventana = document.getElementById("player");
    
    if(ventana.style.display != 'none'){
        ventana.style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        ventana.style.display = '';
    }
}

function fetchMusicDetails(){
    // Poster Image, Pause/Play Image
    $("#playpausebtn img").attr("src", "images/pause-red.png");
    $("#bgImage").attr("src", poster[playlist_index]);
    $("#image").attr("src",poster[playlist_index]);

    // Title and Artist
    playlist_status.innerHTML = title[playlist_index];
    playlist_artist.innerHTML = artists[playlist_index];

    // Audio
    audio.src = dir + playlist[playlist_index] + ext;
    audio.play();
}
function playPause(element){
    let playButton = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
    if(playButton.value == "play"){
        playButton.setAttribute("value","pause");
        player.playVideo()
        $("#playpausebtn img").attr("src","images/pause-red.png");
    }else{
        playButton.setAttribute("value","play");
        player.pauseVideo();
        $("#playpausebtn img").attr("src","images/play-red.png");
    }
}
function nextSong(){
    playlist_index++;
    if(playlist_index > playlist.length - 1){
        playlist_index = 0;
    }
    fetchMusicDetails();
}
function prevSong(){
    playlist_index--;
    if(playlist_index < 0){
        playlist_index = playlist.length - 1;
    }
    fetchMusicDetails();
}
function mute(){
    if(player.isMuted()){
        player.unMute();
        $("#mutebtn img").attr("src","images/speaker.png");
    }else{
        player.mute();
        $("#mutebtn img").attr("src","images/mute.png");
    }
}
function seek(event){
    if(player.getDuration() == 0){
        null;
    }else{
        if(seeking){
            seekslider.value = event.clientX - seekslider.offsetLeft;
            seekto = player.getDuration() *  (seekslider.value / 100);
            player.seekTo(seekto);
        }
    }
}
function setvolume(){
    player.setVolume(volumeslider.value);
}
function seektimeupdate(){
    if(player.getDuration()){
        let nt = player.getCurrentTime() * (100 / player.getDuration());
        seekslider.value = nt;
        var curmins = Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime() / 60);
        var cursecs = Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime() - curmins * 60);
        var durmins = Math.floor(player.getDuration() / 60);
        var dursecs = Math.floor(player.getDuration() - durmins * 60);
        if(cursecs < 10){cursecs = "0" + cursecs}
        if(dursecs < 10){dursecs = "0" + dursecs}
        if(curmins < 10){curmins = "0" + curmins}
        if(durmins < 10){durmins = "0" + durmins}
        curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins + ":" + cursecs;
        durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins + ":" + dursecs;
    }else{
        curtimetext.innerHTML = "00" + ":" + "00";
        durtimetext.innerHTML = "00" + ":" + "00";
    }
}
function switchTrack(){
    if(playlist_index == (playlist.length -1)){
        playlist_index = 0;
    }else{
        playlist_index++;
    }
    fetchMusicDetails();
}
function loop(){
    if(audio.loop){
        audio.loop = false;
        $("#repeat img").attr("src", "images/rep.png");
    }else{
        audio.loop = true;
        $("#repeat img").attr("src", "images/rep1.png");
    }
}
function getRandomNumber(min, max){
    let step1 = max - min + 1;
    let step2 = Math.random() * step1;
    let result = Math.floor(step2) + min;
    return result;
}
function random(){
    let randomIndex = getRandomNumber(0 , playlist.length - 1);
    playlist_index = randomIndex;
    fetchMusicDetails();
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
button{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.music-container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.music-content{
    position: relative;
    width: 245px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-width: 8px 4px !important;
    border: solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .52);
}
#bg-image img{
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    filter: blur(6px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
#blacklayer{
    height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.404);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
#menu{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
#menu img{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#volume-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    z-index: 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#volume-container img{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.slider{
    width: 110px;
    height: 1px !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
}
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #e62c2f;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.slider:active::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
#music-image{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 215px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#circle-image{
    position: absolute;
    top: -33%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,50%);
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid rgba(221,221,221,0.897);
    overflow: hidden;
}
#music-image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#player{
    position: absolute;
    top: -33%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,27%);
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid rgba(221,221,221,0.897);
    overflow: hidden;
}
#music-title{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 25px;
    top: 65%;
    color: #fff;
}
#music-title h5{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0 5px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
#music-title h6{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12.5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#music-menu{
    width: 90%;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#music-menu img{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#visibility{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#currentTime{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    padding: 0 12px 5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
#currentTime span{
    font-size: 12px;
}
.seekslider{
    width: 100px;
    height: 2px !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 3;
    outline: none;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
.seekslider::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #e62c2f;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.seekslider:active::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
#buttons{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#buttons div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.play{
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.play img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.prev img,
.next img{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
#buttons .like{
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    right: 8%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#buttons .like i{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.883);
}
#buttons .repeat{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 6%;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#repeat img{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Music Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="music-container">
        <div class="music-content">
            <div id="bg-image">
                <div id="blackLayer"></div>
                <img src="images/ncs1.jpeg" alt="" id="bgImage">
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <img src="images/menu.png" alt="">
                <img src="images/search.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div id="volume-container">
                <img src="images/volume-low.png" alt="" id="volumn-down">
                <input type="range" class="slider" id="volumeslider" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
                <img src="images/volumn-high.png" alt="" id="volumn-up">
            </div>
            <div id="music-image">
                <div id="circle-image">
                    <div id="player"></div>
                    <img src="images/ncs1.jpeg" alt="" id="image">
                </div>
                <div id="music-title">
                    <h5 id="playlist_status"></h5>
                    <h6 id="playlist_artist"></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="music-menu">
                <button id="random"><img src="images/random.png" alt=""></button>
                <button id="visibility"><img src="images/video-on.png" alt=""></button>
                <button id="mutebtn"><img src="images/speaker.png" alt=""></button>
            </div>
            <div id="currentTime">
                <span id="curtimetext">00:00</span>
                <span id="durtimetext">00:00</span>
            </div>
            <input type="range" class="seekslider" id="seekslider" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
            <div id="buttons">
                <button class="repeat" id="repeat"><img src="images/rep.png" alt=""></button>
                <div>
                    <button class="prev" id="prevbtn"><img src="images/backward.png" alt=""></button>
                    <button class="play" id="playpausebtn" value="play"><img src="images/play-red.png" alt=""></button>
                    <button class="next" id="nextbtn"><img src="images/forward.png" alt=""></button>
                </div>
                <span class="like">
                    <i class="far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

// Manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name" : "OdisseyChromeExtension",
    "description" : "Reproductor de musica youtube",
    "version" : "0.3",
    "browser_action" : {
        "default_popup" : "index.html",
        "default_title" : "odissey"
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api https://www.youtube.com/s/player/9f996d3e/www-widgetapi.vflset/www-widgetapi.js https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js; object-src 'self'",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*" , "https://*/*",
        "cookies",
        "identity",
        "identity.email"
    ]
}
```

This is the extension appearance

[image]

Comment: Might be a quick solution see if it helps.. `* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }` if that doesn't do anything add `font-size: 0; line-height: 0;` just to see if it changes anything.

Comment: might have missunderstood you there.. are you trying to do so that the corners are transparent?

Comment: does anything happen if you do `html, body { clip-path: inset(0, 0, 10rem, 0); }` or will you get a white background?

Comment: didn´t work, I still get the white background.
"are you trying to do so that the corners are transparent?" Yes I´m trying to do that exactly

Comment: @F0RGOTT3NSKY can you add how and where did you add the extension in the main page? Using `iframe` or something?

Comment: I´m going to add the main.js and manifest.json

Comment: the white background is in the iframe in debugger.. adding alpha to bg color fixes the issue.. idk if that helps in any way..

Comment: the official github has examples where they use transparency in bg, if you haven't looked there yet.. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/master/apps/samples

Comment: @F0RGOTT3NSKY try adding `.snippet-box-result {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
}` to your css

Comment: @zergski not working, it seems like Chrome sets the background color to white by default anyway  when I set the background color to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Okey this might actually solve your problem.
As the background is there because of the iframe, embed a player into an `<object>` or `<video>` tag..

```
<object width={ width } height={ height }>
  <video src={ playlists['mylist'].JSON[index].source } type="video/webp" width="100%" height="333" objectFit="cover" />
</object>
```

Then just get a JSON of the playlist. If you want higher functionality like search or managment of user created playlists you need to go through Googles Data API. It can be finicky in the beggining but well worth the time.

here are some code examples:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?apix=true

Otherwise if you have set playlists in the player, you can just datamine separately and create your own JSON arrays, even manually its really simple and won't even take a minute per list when you have your mining snippet. A small upside here is you can dynamically create custom playlists outside of youtube.

[image]

then you can have three players and have them preload the previous and next video for a smoother switching experience ( an option for a fade inbetween can also be nice )

I have snippets of code somewhere for this kind of setup, if this sounds like something you care to do I can try to dig them up for you.

happy coding! :)